# Cyclic subgroup of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is there any non trivial example of subgroup of a cyclic group?

Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. I couldnt find any non trivial examples of it since every subgroup would have the generator and if the generator is there then the entire group is there.

Comment: $\{0 + 4\mathbb Z, 2 + 4\mathbb Z\} \subseteq Z/4\mathbb Z$ for a finite example, or think of $n\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Wow i totally missed that thanks.

Comment: And from the answer below, you conclude that if the order is prime, there is no proper subgroup at all.

Comment: That was going to be my next question. You read my mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every subgroup has to contain the generator. Consider the cyclic group of order $4$, which we denote as $\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}$. Then $\{1,a^2\}$ is a proper subgroup.

More generally, if $\langle a \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $x$ and $d$ divides $x$, we have a cyclic subgroup $\langle a^d \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

If your group is $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)$, your generator is $1$.  If your subgroup is $H=(2\mathbb{Z},+)$, the generator is $2$ which is not the generator for $G$.